# Storing multiple get.arguments in a dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am receiving html form data and want to store two of these values as a dict in with one key.

I have:

```
 Data={
       'Name': self.get_argument('Name'),
       'Email': self.get_argument('Email'),
       'Tel': [self.get_arguments('telType[]'),self.get_arguments('tel[]')],
        ......

 }
```

This gives a result of `'Tel': [[u'Work', u'Home'], [u'123456789', u'0000001111223']]`.

How can you store it as: `{u'Work:u'123456789'}` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
data = {'Tel': [[u'Work', u'Home'], [u'123456789', u'0000001111223']]}
data["Tel"] = dict(zip(*data["Tel"]))
{'Tel': {u'Home': u'0000001111223', u'Work': u'123456789'}}
```

`zip` adds the corresponding elements from each list to tuples:

```
In [18]: data = {'Tel': [[u'Work', u'Home'], [u'123456789', u'0000001111223']]}

In [19]: zip(*data["Tel"])
Out[19]: [(u'Work', u'123456789'), (u'Home', u'0000001111223')]
```

`dict(*zip)` creates key value pairs based on the tuple contents:

```
In [20]: dict(zip(*data["Tel"]))
Out[20]: {u'Home': u'0000001111223', u'Work': u'123456789'}
```

Comment: (+1) Beat me to it :-)

Comment: @user94628, no prob, you're welcome, zip is definitely something worth knowing.

Answer (score 3):

`self.get_arguments('telType[]')` is a list of types of phone numbers.

`self.get_arguments('tel[]')` is a list of phone numbers.

To fit these two together, you can use `zip` to build tuples of `(telType, tel)`. Then, you can turn these into a dictionary by calling `dict` on the list of tuples:

```
Data={
    # ...
    'Tel': dict(zip(self.get_argument('telType[]'), self.get_arguments('tel[]')))
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Tel':{
        self.get_arguments('telType[]')[0] : self.get_arguments('tel[]')[0],
        self.get_arguments('telType[]')[1] : self.get_arguments('tel[]')[1]

      }
```

Comment: there i included a square bracket in the answer @hlt

Comment: Still doesn't work. `Data['Tel']` will look like `{'Work': [u'Work', u'Home'], 'Home': [u'123456789', u'0000001111223']}`

Comment: Looks better, but what if you get three phone numbers? Or fourty-two? Or only one?

Comment: wont work then would have to add fields manually to handle that case I didn't know about 'zip'